# Finding Months Difference in Days

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the difference between two dates which should be exact in months like if the date difference is greater than 182 days them on 183rd Day it should show as 7 Months.I tried below one,

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(DATEDIFF(DD,'2018-01-01 18:45:30.203',GETDATE()) as float)/30,0)
```

but it has 15 days difference.

Comment: The reason your answer is off by 15 days is because you are rounding.  You might want to use CEILING instead of ROUND.   But, as scsimon says, you're on the wrong track dividing by 30.  If you divide by 30, 182 and 183 will give you the same result.

Comment: What answer do you expect when the pair of datetimes are:    2018-01-17 and 2018-02-16;    2018-01-17 and 2018-02-17;    2018-01-17 and 2018-02-18;    2018-01-17T18:00:00.000 and 2018-02-17T17:59:59.999;   2018-01-17T18:00:00.000 and 2018-02-17T18:00:00.001?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t use 30. It’s fail on some months. For example Jan 1 and March 2 since February doesn’t have at least 30 days. But I think this is what you are after. If the current day isn’t the first of the month then add a month.

```
SELECT 
   Case 
        when datepart(day,getdate()) > 1
        Then datediff(month,'2018-01-01 18:45:30.203',GETDATE()) + 1
        Else datediff(month,'2018-01-01 18:45:30.203',GETDATE())
    End
```

Comment: I don't think OP intends that there is anything special about the first day of the month.  And I think the day-of-month, and even time-of-day are relevant.  Let's hope OP can make the question less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I think that calculating the difference in months as an integer is very similar to calculating the age of a person. We can take the DATEDIFF in months, add this number of months to the first date and compare that to the second date to decide whether we have to subtract 1 from the difference:

```
DECLARE @Date1 datetime = '2018-01-01 18:45:30.203';
DECLARE @Date2 datetime = GETDATE();

SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @Date1, @Date2), @Date1) > @Date2
    THEN DATEDIFF(month, @Date1, @Date2) - 1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(month, @Date1, @Date2)
  END
```